# What are the Costs of Offensive Drugs and Poisons?

Tags: pricing, poison, cyberpunk-2020, medicine-and-drugs

What are the costs of offensive drugs and poisons in *Cyberpunk 2020*? That is, the various types of drugs and poison set out in the Friday Night Firefight section that can be delivered via airgun, dartgun, or squirtgun.

I can find effects but not rules. It is referenced under the Ammunition section in the Gear chapter, but different types are not priced differently (which clearly is not the intention.) If possible, I would prefer rules set out in the Core Rulebook.

Answer (score 3):

On p. 64 of the Cyberpunk 2020 corebook, the cost for drugged ammunition for airguns is given as being 5 times the base price of that ammunition. The type of the drug used does not appear to be relevant in determining the cost.